# Tomcat cannot change port to 80

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

Hello i have installed `Tomcat8` on my Ubuntu Server and by default it was setup on port 8080 so i changed the port to 80 from the `server.xml` file, but when i start my server i get this following exceptions:

```
02-Aug-2017 19:15:00.733 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]


java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:982)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:244)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:997)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Ca

talina.load(Catalina.java:630)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)

02-Aug-2017 19:15:00.736 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:630)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:999)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:982)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:244)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:997)
    ... 13 more
```

Now my server could not start because of this problem What should i do to fix this problem ?

Comment: Sounds like the process does not have permission to bind to a privileged port. What use account do you start the server process under?

Comment: I was logged in as Root user

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/112795/how-to-run-a-server-on-port-80-as-a-normal-user-on-linux

Comment: No sir this is not duplicate and i have seen the other questions before i wrote mine.My problem is not how to change the port!

Comment: @MontaserQasem That is not an answer to my question if you think about it. My question was about the server process, not about how you were logged in.

Comment: Can you try -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true once.

Comment: How can i apply it ?

Comment: java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true Test.java

Comment: Actually i don't follow what are you trying to do but i did what you asked anyway and it gives me Error:Could not fund or load main class

Comment: Sorry I forgot you are working on a tomcat environment.Can you try setting an environment variable .Can you put JAVA_OPTS= $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses to the catalina.sh startup script.

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate. Just read past the accepted windows-based answer